# Updating one UISegmentedControl with the value of another UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to click a button and make the value of one UISegmentedControl go into a second identical UISegmented control.

Here is the code I tried, which does nothing:

```
    _stopFractionControl = _startFractionControl;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really easy:

1. Create an `IBAction` for the segment control
2. The rest lies within the action

---

```
-(IBAction)segmentAction:(sender)
{
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex=segmentedControl2.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [segmentedControl1 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want this tied to a UISegmentedControl action. I want this result tied to another UIButton click. Any ideas?

Comment: This does not work in a UIButton:` stopFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex=startFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [stopFractionControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: I cant understand you properly....if you want this to be done in a button action then simply add the same code in the button action method. This will make the 2nd segment control to replicate the state of the 1st segment control.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a full object to another object but all you need to do is change a parameter of the first object in relation with a parameter of another object.
So, what you need to change is the `selectedSegmentIndex` parameter of your `UISegmentController` object:

Try:

```
//get segment index of a UISegmentedController object
NSInteger otherSegmentIndex = _startFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex

//set segment index of a UISegmentedController object to the above
[_stopFractionControl setSelectedSegmentIndex: otherSegmentIndex];

//implement the change
[_stopFractionControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: I feel like this is the right direction but I am getting a grip of errors. I will play with it. `Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC`

Comment: Another hit. `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'NSNumber *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')`

Comment: Last one. `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')`

Comment: I am getting the previous errors based on the following code:`NSNumber *otherSegmentIndex = _startFractionControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    
    //set segment index of a UISegmentedController object to the above
    [_stopFractionControl setSelectedSegmentIndex: otherSegmentIndex];
    
    //implement the change
    [_stopFractionControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: @C_Dub : (_mine and @AnubrataSantra 's answer are almost identical_) anyways... updated answer. it should be `NSInteger`. btw... the `-sendActionsForControlEvents` is required or else it'll be just a visual change